# Repeatable Custom groups w/ required field

Tags: custom-fields, multi-record

I am unable to save a contact with a that has 2 or more repeatable custom groups with a required custom field. The validation fails.

I am using CiviCrm 4.7.9. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: David- may be worth setting up a comparable but simplified set of fields on demo and confirming if the problem occurs there and hopefully others will take a look before the demo site gets refreshed

Comment: I added the Custom Group "Repeating field set" witch a single required custom field to http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/.

Here is a video of how to reproduce the error: https://youtu.be/xWIHBj5XiEs

Comment: Exactly 2 years later and I'm seeing this with CiviCRM 4.7.27 on WordPress. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never did find a solution.

Comment: I have reported it as an issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/274 (or at least I think I have - my first attempt at this)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this out on the demo sites (WordPress and Drupal) CiviCRM 5.5.alpha1 and its still not working. I'll look into reporting it as a bug, but I have found a partial work round (though this isn't what I want).

The problem only occurs with the custom field set using the inline option, so you could use tab or tab with table.

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: Oh something changed! By 'repeatable' I presume you mean multi-record. used to be that could 'only' work as a Tab but now I see the Help says "'Tab with Table' is recommended for customs data sets which allow multiple records." which implies it 'might' work with 'inline'

Comment: That's certainly how I am interpreting this question and the problem I have. I see that in the help now, but it only says recommended. The option change when you select multi-record so if inline wasn't mean to work it should be removed (not the solution I want). The documentation suggests all should work, though its a bit muddled in that it doesn't say the tab with table is only for multi-record.